# Passing up information in a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm new to programming, and learning python right now. I am building a system in which every object consists of a singleton elements or binary set (of sets of sets..) containing singleton elements or binary sets, i.e., a recursive structure. Within these objects, I have defined a function that gives me immediate containment, and a recursive function that answers the question whether an element is contained in any of the sets members, recursively. Binary Sets and Singletons are subclasses of the metaclass "syntactic object". Every object has a unique identifier, idx, and every object can in principle occur in multiple places, so we could have a set such as the following, with idx attached to the object as -idx

{{A-0,C-2}-4, {B-1, {C-2, {D-3, {A-0,C-2}-4}-5}-6}-7

```
    class SOMeta(object):
    """Abstract class, never instantiated. Has two subtypes, base case, recursive case"""

    def __init__(self, idx: int):
        self.idx = idx


    def i_contains(self, a):
        """self immediately contains a if a is an element of self"""
        if type(self) is Binary:
            return a in self.syntactic_object_set
        else:
            return False

    def contains(self, a):
        """self contains a if self immediately contains a, or some daughter of self contains a"""
        if type(self) is Binary:
            if self.i_contains(a):
                return True
            else:
                to_return = False
                for daughter in self.syntactic_object_set:
                    if type(daughter) is Binary:
                        to_return = to_return or daughter.contains(a)
                return to_return
        else:
            return False

    class Binary(SOMeta):
    def __init__(self, the_set: Set[SOMeta], idx: int):
        super(Binary, self).__init__(idx)
        self.syntactic_object_set: Set[SOMeta] = the_set

    def __str__(self):
        set_strings = {str(obj) for obj in self.syntactic_object_set}
        rep = "< " + str(self.idx) + ": " + ", ".join(set_strings) + " >"
        return rep


    class Singleton(SOMeta):

    def __init__(self, lexical_item: string, idx: int):
        super(Singleton, self).__init__(idx)
        self.lexical_item = lexical_item

    def __str__(self):
        rep = "< " + str(self.idx) + ": " + str(self.lexical_item) + " >"
        return rep
```

Now, based on this, I am trying to define a function that returns a set of "paths" of an object within an object, starting at the top, where a path is defined as follows:
a path is a sequence of objects < O_1, O_2,..., O_n > where for all 0 < i < n, O_{i+1} is in O_i.

So, for example, if the set in question is {A-0, {B-1,A-0}-2}-3, I want this function to return the following set of lists:
{[{A-0, {B-1,A-0}-2}-3, A-0], [{A-0, {B-1,A-0}-2}-3, {B-1,A-0}-2, A-0]}

I have tried the following recursive function, which works well in the base cases, and the above case, but seems to run into trouble with larger sets. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong in the way that I try to pass up path_set in the function?

```
    def paths(self, so):
        """
        :return: all paths to self starting at so 
        """
        def paths_recursive(self, other, path, path_set = set()):
            """ Helper Function """
            for x in so.syntactic_object_set:                
                if x.idx == self.idx:
                    path += [self]
                    path_set.update([tuple(path)])

                elif type(x) != Singleton:
                    if x.contains(self):
                        path1 = path.copy() # Need to make a copy in case both daughters contain self
                        path1 += [x]
                        path_set.update(paths_recursive(self, x, path1, path_set))
            return path_set

        if so.contains(self) == False:
                    return {}
        elif so.idx == self.idx:
            return {self}
        else:
            return paths_recursive(self, so, list([so]))
```